# State is not synchronized

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I have the following problem:

I want to show some products. When you press the Next button, then the goForward() is called and you can see the next product.
My problem is when the submit() is called after pressing another button called Submit, the values variable does not contain the current productId of the product that is shown. Instead of this, it contains itsinitial value.
What is wrong?

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        activeIndex: 0
    };
    this.submit = this.submit.bind(this);
    this.goForward= this.goForward.bind(this);
  }

  submit(values) {
    console.log(values);
  }

  goForward() {
    let index = this.state.activeIndex;
    let productsSize = products.length - 1;

    if (index === productsSize) {
      index = -1;
    }

    ++index;

    this.setState({
      activeIndex: index
    });
  }

  render() {
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.submit)} name="edit">
          {this.props.products.map((product, index) => (
          <ProductDetails
          productId={product.productId}
          price={product.price}
          />
          ))}
    </form>
  }


let MyProductComponent = reduxForm({ form: "edit", enableReinitialize: true
})
(MyComponent);

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    initialValues: {
      productId: formValueSelector("edit")(
        state,
        "activeIndex"
      )
    }
  };
};

MyProductComponent = withRouter(
  connect(mapStateToProps)(toJS(MyProductComponent))
);
```

Comment: Pardon me, but I'm unable to see `state.activeIndex` being used anywhere within the render method.
Or even the use of `goForward` method. Moreover, won't it be `this.goForward = this.goForward.bind(this);` in your constructor?

Comment: @SajalPreetSingh this.goForward = this.goForward.bind(this); is used in the constructor. I am also using the this.state.activeIndex in the goForward(). I dont need it in the render method(). I just want it in the initial values.

Comment: Would be appreciated if you share a fiddle.

Comment: @KathrineHanson here's a working [`redux-form` fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/036ur33k/42/). You can fork it and create a working example. It would help to all of us in order to support you.

Answer (score 0):

you should be using setState with functional parameter

```
this.setState(oldState => {
  let index = oldState.activeIndex;
  let productsSize = products.length - 1;

  if (index === productsSize) {
    index = -1;
  }

  ++index;

  return {
    activeIndex: index
  };
});
```

this is essentially all that happens in your `goForward` method

The point here is that whenever your new state is derived from the old state, you should be using the functional syntax instead of the object syntax.

Comment: I just did that change and the productId holds its initial value again.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your `handleSubmit` (which you haven't included so it's hard to tell exactly what might be going on) is not calling `preventDefault` and your form is actually being submitted and reloading the page -- giving you the initial value again.

Here's a quick sample component (based off of yours), but it uses `preventDefault` and shows that your state logic is working properly:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      activeIndex: 0
    };
    this.submit = this.submit.bind(this);
    this.goForward = this.goForward.bind(this);
  }

  submit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  goForward() {
    let index = this.state.activeIndex;
    let productsSize = this.props.products.length - 1;

    if (index === productsSize) {
      index = -1;
    }

    ++index;

    this.setState({
      activeIndex: index
    });
    console.log(this.state.activeIndex);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.submit} name="edit">
        {this.props.products.map((product, index) => (
          <div key={product}>{product}</div>
        ))}
        <button onClick={this.goForward}>FWD</button>
      </form>
    )
  }
}
```